# What is the Purpose of the FilterScope parameter in Ninject BindFIlter<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, actionfilterattribute

Please can someone explain what the `FilterScope` is for in the `BindFilter<>` method?

I'm using the following:

```
kernel.BindFilter<QuizExists>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Controller, null).WhenControllerHas<QuizExistsAttribute>();

kernel.BindFilter<QuizExists>(System.Web.Mvc.FilterScope.Action, null).WhenActionMethodHas<QuizExistsAttribute>();
```

It seems that the `FilterScope` affects the order in which the Attributes are executed, however there is a second parameter for that, which is `order`.

What gives?

Answer (score 4):

The comments in the [documentation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/wiki/Conditional-bindings-for-filters) are pretty clear on what the `FilterScope` is for. It restricts the scope of the filter to either the `Controller` level or the `Action` level.

Although the `order` parameter doesn't appear to be documented, I would assume that it controls the order in which the filters are applied if more than one applies to a single controller or action. For example, you would be able to run an `AuditFilter` before a `LogFilter` regardless of the order they are registered in. This is especially important if you are applying some filter attributes to the controller directly and registering other filter attributes through Ninject - without this parameter there would be no way to tell the framework which order to apply them.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense though, because the filter is of a certain type already, such as `IActionFilter` `IAuthorizationFilter`.  If I have one of each the FilterScope takes no effect... any ideas?

Comment: Yes, a filter is a certain type, but if you look at how (for example) `AuthorizeAttribute` is registered, it can be at the global level (in `GlobalFilters.Filters`) which will always run, the controller level which will run for any action within a controller, or the action level. All this is doing is mimicking that behavior.